# The program is fine, but if no errors are found, it cannot be executed

Tags: python

This is the program I wrote. I tested it in pycharm. There is nothing wrong with the program, but it cannot be executed.
The main function is to input AD, and the program can output century.

```
#for 
#year=1905,year=1700
#1=<year=<2005
#solution(year)=20
#solution(year)=17
```

I cannot find the errors. It's Python.

```
def solution(year):
    century=math.ceil(year/100)
    if year%100==0:
    century-=1
    return century

century=solution(year)
print(solution(year))
```

Comment: Please post what command you used and the output of the command

Comment: Please explain what "cannot be executed" means. What error message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in python text indentation is very important (tabulators).

To make your code work, you need

1. import math (library which contains definition for `floor()` function)
2. add an indentation
3. use variables where they are defined

Working code:

```
import math
def solution(year):
    century=math.floor(year/100)
    if year%100!=0:
        century+=1
    return century


print(solution(1920))
```

Explanation:
in 4th line, we are checking the modulo operation output. If its 0, we increase the century by 1. Then we return the value of century. If year % 100 equals 0, we don't increase value of century variable.

You also need to understand the scope of variables. Year is defined as parameter in solution function. Its not accessible outside of it.

In those lines:

```
century=solution(year)
print(solution(year))
```

You need to specify the year explicitly. You can also define additional variable `year` and assign value to it. Therefore, this will be totally different variable than `year` defined inside the `solution()` function. If you want to read further about this topic, search for "variable shadowing".

Comment: thank you for your reply. but the century output for 1700AD is incorrect.

Comment: @陳冠璇 The result is `16`. Which value do you expect?

Comment: 1700AD is the 17th century.

Comment: @陳冠璇 In this case, this code need some changes. Lets change ```ceil()``` function to ```floor()``` function, which will round down. Then in ```if``` statement we will check if the modulo doesn't equal 0 (```if year%100!=0:```). If this condition is met, we increase the century by 1. See the original answer updated

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
def solution(year):
    century=math.ceil(year/100)
    if year%100==0:
        century-=1
    return century
```

test for year 2000

```
year = 2000
century=solution(year )
print(century)
```